# Проблема с реализацией абстрактного класса С++

Tags: c++, наследование, интерфейс

Имею абстрактный класс

```
template<typename T>
struct Triplet{
   int i;
   int j;
   T b;
};
template<typename T>
class Matrices
{
public:
   // Виртуальный деструктор
   virtual ~Matrices() = 0;
   /*
    * Виртуальные методы, должны быть реализованы вашим классом
    */
   virtual void fill(vector<Triplet<T>> &matrix) = 0;
   virtual const Matrices<T> operator+(const Matrices<T> &matrix) const = 0;
   virtual const Matrices<T> operator-(const Matrices<T> &matrix) const = 0;
   virtual const Matrices<T> operator*(const Matrices<T> &matrix) const = 0;
   virtual const Matrices<T> operator*(T& k) const = 0;
   virtual const Matrices<T> operator*(const T& k) const = 0;
   virtual T& operator()(int row, int col) = 0;
   virtual const T& operator()(int row, int col) const = 0;
};
```

Наследую его в своем классе

```
template<typename T>
class DOK: public Matrices<T>{
private:
    /*
     * Dictionary of Keys, pair<int, int> is coordinates of non-zero elements,
     * next int is value
     */
    map<pair<int, int>, T> dict;
    int size_n;
    int size_m;
   // int count;
public:

    DOK(vector<Triplet<T>> &matrix, int n, int m);
    DOK(int n, int m);
    ~DOK(){};
    void fill(vector<Triplet<T>> &matrix);
    void insert(const Triplet<T> &Element);
    void resize(int n, int m);
    void print() const;


    const DOK<T> operator+(const DOK<T> &matrix) const;
    const DOK<T> operator-(const DOK<T> &matrix) const;
    const DOK<T> operator*(const DOK<T> &matrix) const;
    const DOK<T> operator*(T& k) const;
    const DOK<T> operator*(const T& k) const;

    T& operator()(int row, int col);
    const T& operator()(int row, int col) const;
};

template<typename T>
void operator+=(DOK<T>& left, const DOK<T>& right){
    left=left+right;
}
template<typename  T>
void operator-=(DOK<T>& left, const DOK<T>& right){
    left = left - right;
}
template<typename  T>
void operator*=(DOK<T>& left, const DOK<T>& right){
    left = left * right;
}
template<typename  T>
void operator*=(DOK<T>& left, T& k){
    left = left*k;
}
template<typename  T>
void operator*=(DOK<T>& left,const T& k){
    left = left*k;
}

template<typename  T>
const DOK<T> operator*(T& k, const DOK<T> &matrix){
    return matrix*k;
}
template<typename  T>
const DOK<T> operator*(const T& k, const DOK<T> &matrix){
    return matrix*k;
}

template<typename  T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const DOK<T> &matrix){
    matrix.DOK<T>::print();
    return os;
}
```

Реализация:

```
template<typename  T>
DOK<T>::DOK(int n, int m){
    this->resize(n, m);
}
template<typename  T>
DOK<T>::DOK(vector<Triplet<T>> &matrix, int n, int m) {
    //cout<<"Input height and weight of matrix: "<<endl;
    //cin>>n>>m;
    this->resize(n, m);
    this->fill(matrix);
}
template<typename  T>
void DOK<T>::fill(vector<Triplet<T>> &matrix) {
    //this->count=matrix.size();
    //cout<<"Input your coordinates with value in format \"i j val\" "<<endl;
    for(int k = 0; k < matrix.size(); k++){
        this->insert(matrix[k]);
    }
}
/*
 * Inserts element with coordinates i, j and value b in matrix
 */
template<typename  T>
void DOK<T>::insert(const Triplet<T> &Element){
    try {
        if(Element.i > this->size_n || Element.j > size_m) throw 1;
        pair<int, int> coordinates = {Element.i, Element.j};
        this->dict.insert(make_pair(coordinates, Element.b));
    }
    catch (int a) {
        cout<<"Inserting coordinates {"<<Element.i<<", "<<Element.j<<"} out of range. "<<endl;
    }
}
template<typename  T>
void DOK<T>::resize(int n, int m){
    this->size_n=n;
    this->size_m=m;
}
template<typename  T>
const DOK<T> DOK<T>::operator+(const DOK<T> &matrix) const{
    try{
        if(this->size_n != matrix.size_n || this->size_m != matrix.size_m) throw 1;
        DOK<T> M = *this;
        for(auto j: matrix.dict){
            if(M.dict.find(j.first)!=M.dict.cend()) {
                M.dict[j.first] += j.second;
            }else{
                M.dict.insert({j.first, j.second});
                //M.count++;
            }
        }
        return M;
    }
    catch (int a) {
        cout<<"Sizes of Matrices are different."<<endl;
    }
}
template<typename  T>
const DOK<T> DOK<T>::operator-(const DOK<T> &matrix) const{
    return -1.*matrix+*this;
}
template<typename  T>
 void DOK<T>::print() const {
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i = 1; i <= this->size_n; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= this->size_m; j++){
            if(this->dict.find({i, j})!= this->dict.cend()) cout<<this->dict.find(make_pair(i, j))->second<<" "; else cout<<0<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}



template<typename  T>
const DOK<T> DOK<T>::operator*(const DOK<T> &matrix) const{
    try {
        if(this->size_m != matrix.size_n) throw 1;
        DOK<T> M = DOK(this->size_n, matrix.size_m);
        for (int i = 1; i <= this->size_n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= matrix.size_m; j++) {
                T a=0;
                for(int k = 1; k<=this->size_m; k++){
                    if(this->dict.find({i,k}) != this->dict.cend() && matrix.dict.find({k, j})!=matrix.dict.cend()){
                        a+=this->dict.find({i,k})->second*matrix.dict.find({k,j})->second;
                        //cout<<a<<endl;
                    }
                }
                Triplet<T> m = {i, j, a};
                M.insert(m);
            }
        }
        return M;
    }
    catch (int a) {
        cout<<"Wrong sizes of matrices to multiplication"<<endl;
    }
}

template<typename  T>
const DOK<T> DOK<T>::operator*(T& k) const{
    DOK<T> M = *this;
    for(auto i: M.dict){
        M.dict[i.first]*=k;
    }
    return M;
}
template<typename  T>
const DOK<T> DOK<T>::operator*(const T& k) const{
    DOK<T> M = *this;
    for(auto i: M.dict){
        M.dict[i.first]*=k;
    }
    return M;
}

template<typename  T>
 T& DOK<T>::operator()(int row, int col){
    return this->dict.find({row, col})->second;
}
template<typename  T>
const T& DOK<T>::operator()(int row, int col) const{
    return this->dict.find({row, col})->second;
}
```

В итоге при попытке создания на стеке экземпляра дочернего класса DOK получаю такую ошибку, будто бы реализаций трех чисто виртуальных методов нет

```
DOK<double> p = DOK<double>(in, 3, 3);
```

```
Allocating an object of abstract class type 'DOK<double>'
unimplemented pure virtual method 'operator+' in 'DOK'
unimplemented pure virtual method 'operator-' in 'DOK'
unimplemented pure virtual method 'operator*' in 'DOK'

In instantiation of template class 'DOK<double>' virtual function 'operator*' has a different return type ('const DOK<double>') than the function it overrides (which has return type 'const Matrices<double>')
```

Никак не могу найти проблему, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: А что возвращают все эти операторы в абстрактном классе?..  const Matrices<T>, а вы определяете  в DOK операторы, возвращаемый тип и аргументы которых отличаются       DOK<T> это не Matrices<T>. И для чего тут абстрактный класс вообще?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первая проблема:

- Вы пытаетесь возвращать объект(не ссылку и не указатель) абстрактного
  класса из операторов. Объект абстрактного класса невозможно создать,
  следовательно не возможно вернуть такой объект из какой либо функции.

Вторая проблема:

- Абстрактные классы предназначены для обеспечения интерфейсом
  (возможно и  некоторыми данными) своим производным классам и
  возможности написать рудиментарный код, не зависящий от того, объект
  какого производного класса участвует. Поэтому, для данного случая,
  написанный абстрактный класс не имеет никакого смысла, если даже исправить все ошибки.

Третья проблема:

- Производные классы должны переопределить все чистые виртуальные
  функции абстрактного класса точно с таким же набором аргументов и
  возвращаемого типа, что объявлено в абстрактном классе, иначе
  функция_член не определена, и этот производный класс сам является
  абстрактным.

Если вы хотите все же исправить, а не написать без базового класса, то покажу на одном операторе.

```
template<typename T>
class Matrices
{
    //...
public:
    // Виртуальный деструктор
    virtual ~Matrices() = 0;
    //...
    //сначала определим +=, чтобы возвращать ссылку, а не другой объект
    virtual  Matrices<T>& operator+=(const Matrices<T>&)  = 0;   
};

template<typename T>
class DOK : public Matrices<T> {
private:
    /*  
     ...
     */
public:
    //...
    /*ключевое слово override подсказывает компилятору, что пытаемся
     переопределять член базового класса. Компилятор сам проверит сигнатуру функции
     и в случаи ошибки, сообщит об этом*/
    Matrices<T>& operator+=(const Matrices<T>&)   override
    {
        // ваш код
        return *this;
    }
    //теперь можно написать и оператор +, что принадлежит только этому классу
    const DOK<T> operator+(const DOK<T>& d) const
    {
        DOK<T> t;
        return t += d;
    }
};
```

Или можете написать независимый шаблон оператора, чтобы  использовать для любого типа:

```
 template<class M>
 const M operator+(const M& m) const
 {
    M t;
    return t += m;
 }
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что в таком случае мы не можем сделать чисто виртуальные функции для операторов + - *, а реализуем их через соответствующие += -= *=?

Comment: Можете, но только они должны возвращать ссылку или указатель. Если устраивает такой непрактичный вариант, это отражает ваши намерения, то можно. Только нужно думать что возвращать, потому что ссылку на локальный объект нельзя вернуть.

Comment: Намерения в том, что от этого абстрактного класса должны наследовать еще 2 человека и написать 2 класса, схожие с моим DOK, в которых будут реализованы именно такие операторы и функции. И еще я не совсем понял момент в примере с оператором +. Когда он вызывается, мы применяем переопределенный оператор +=, который работает с объектами типа Matrices<T>, но посылаем мы ему на вход объекты DOK<Т> соответственно как operator+= может воздействовать на DOK<T>, если по сути он должен суммировать элементы мапы, находящейся в DOK<T>?

Comment: Нет, оператор +=,   работает не с объектами Matrices<T>(такие объекты не могут быть),  а с объектами, на которые может ссылаться  Matrices<T>&, а она может ссылаться на объекты любого производного класса.

Comment: Теперь все понятно, спасибо

Comment: Там, где мы переопределяем оператор += вы написали return *this;
У меня на этом месте выдает ошибку
Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
И в остальных местах, где есть this в переопределении
В реализации должно быть DOK<T>::operator+() или Matrices<T>::operator+()?

Comment: Конечно DOK<T>::operator+(), абстрактный класс не имеет этого оператора

Comment: От части помогло. Теперь я могу создавать объект в хипе через
Matrices<double>* k = new DOK<double>(in, 3, 3);
Но при попытке сделать тоже самое на стеке
Matrices<double> p = DOK<double>(in, 3, 3);
Компилятор говорит, что все виртуалы не переопределены

Comment: Я же написал в ответе:  "Производные классы должны переопределить все чистые виртуальные функции абстрактного класса точно с таким же набором аргументов и возвращаемого типа, что объявлено в абстрактном классе, иначе функция_член не определена, *и этот производный класс сам является абстрактным*."  Если вы не ясно все представляете,  вероятнее вы всегда напишете что то не то... Лучше в данном случаи отказаться от абстрактного класса, чтобы любой производный класс имел право  не переопределять то определение, что есть в базовом классе.

Comment: Я понял это и переопределил все функции
Вот мой абстрактный класс https://pastebin.com/Ki1kBMh9
Вот описалово класса  DOK https://pastebin.com/2pZY10cW
Вот реализации https://pastebin.com/p232XhRj

Comment: Кажется это долго... У вас не верное представление о ссылке.     Перемещать временный объект в простую ссылку _ как это можно представлять? Ссылки ссылаются только на Lvalue. Это не rvalue ссылка. Не аозмлжно все рассказать в комментариях, лучше старайтесь разобраться самостоятельно или обратитесь  , преподавателю или  к друзьям

Comment: Если бы тут были смайлы из аськи, я бы уже бился головой о стену, спасибо вам за подсказки!
На последок уточню, вы сейчас написали о том, что я делал в реализациях Matrices<T> M = *this; return move(M); ?

Comment: да, я об этом, но там кажется не только эта ошибка. Биться головой не нужно, а нужно брать учебники и изучать все внимательно.

Comment: Почитал по темам, на которые вы меня нацелили, внимательно посмотрел код, нашел кучу ошибок, но один вопрос так и остался открыт. Пришел к пониманию, почему нужно реализовывать перегрузку именно так, как написали вы в ответе, сделал тоже самое, но встретился с проблемой, что поля, определенные в классе DOK и с которыми надо работать в реализации этой перегрузки, не определены в классе Matrices и компилятор ругается, что он их не знает для ссылки, принимаемой по аргументу https://pastebin.com/zFvffNLT

Comment: Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, это не значит, что я буду сопровождать весь ваш код  и рассказать что и как реализовать. Каждый класс имеет свои данные. Базовый класс не имеет доступ к полям производного класса. Ни один класс не имеет доступ к закрытым членам другого класса, если это даже базовый и т.д.и т.п.  Ну нельзя так _ старайтесь осмыслить что делаете. Еще раз, на SO  помогают разобраться в конкретных вопросах, это сервис вопросов и ответов, а не наемных учителей или помощников для сопровождения кодов. Задавайте другой вопрос, если он у вас возник.